# React component disappears in a blink when using useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I use this the `labs` field only gets updated for a millisecond and is gone after that.

```js
  // the pagination component
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    pageCount: 0,
    currentPage: 0,
    labs: [],
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    labPageCount()
      .then((res) => setState({ ...state, pageCount: res.data.pageCount }))
      .catch(console.log);
  }, [state.pageCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLabs(state.currentPage)
      .then((res) => setState({ ...state, labs: res.data }))
      .catch(console.log);
  }, [state.currentPage]);
```

Now if I add `labs` to the array in the second `useEffect()`, then it results in an infinite loop:-

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    fetchLabs(state.currentPage)
      .then((res) => setState({ ...state, labs: res.data }))
      .catch(console.log);
  }, [state.currentPage, state.labs]);
```

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(state.labs)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the second snipped, you are changing the labs by calling `setState`, then you are watching the changes on `state.labs` which causes the hook to be run again.

Somehow you need to compare labs then if they are different you should `setState`.

Alternatively you can call fetchLabs where you change the labs instead of calling in `useEffect` hook.

Comment: Why does the first one not work? On the first load the value of the currentPage decides which lab page be searched. What actually happens is that the lab array gets updated for a second and then again becomes an empty array. What is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

`state` updates in `react` are `asynchronous` so if you are setting `state` multiple times at different places in code. then directly using the `...state` variable to get the previous value might not work as expected.
Instead of setting a state like this -

```
setState({ ...state, pageCount: res.data.pageCount })
```

Try out this to get the previous value from the state -

```
setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, pageCount: res.data.pageCount }))
```

And you need not add `state.labs` in dependency array, it will going to cause infinite loop if you are changing value of dependency array inside same `useEffect`.